# can HSTS be considered as a remediation for not using secure flag for a pci dss auditor

Tags: cookies, pci-dss, hsts

can HSTS be considered asa remediation for  the vulneraberabity "cookies are not protected by secure flag" for a PCI DSS auditor?

Answer (score 3):

I would be very concerned about this approach if I saw it as a QSA.

Technically speaking you could argue that HSTS is a mitigation as long as you ensure that the HSTS expiry time is always longer than the cookie expiry time. However, this is an incredibly fragile configuration, leaving you open to cookie leaks over HTTP if the expiry times are not calculated and maintained properly. This is not a reasonable expectation in the long-term, because it's too easy for someone to make a mistake or oversight in a future change.

The Secure flag has different behaviours than HSTS when it comes to other attributes, and this leads to a lot of edge-cases and footguns if you're trying to use HSTS as a way to sidestep around using the Secure flag.

If you set a cookie without the Secure flag, from `example.com`, by default it has a SameSite policy of "lax", which means that `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com` also have access to that cookie. If HSTS is not configured for the subdomains, you'll leak the cookie. If you set the Domain attribute, this can have similar implications.

Another issue is that cookies without the Secure flag can be overwritten from a non-secure context. This means that a HTTP connection could be tampered with by an attacker to overwrite the cookie value. HSTS is not a concrete mitigation here, since if the HSTS rule expires on the browser (or the user is visiting the site for the first time in that browser) then the first connection may be HTTP. Additionally, cookies can be set across subdomains and from subdomain to naked domain (RFC 6265), so if there's a HTTP server on `foo.example.com` and your site on `bar.example.com` or `example.com`, an attacker can MitM the plaintext connection and overwrite/set the cookie value for the secure site. This cannot be done if the cookie is first set with the Secure flag from the server, or if the cookie uses the `__Secure-` prefix, which is only allowed to be set from a secure origin.

From a risk analysis perspective, I'd want a very good reason as to why you could fix the HSTS header but not the Secure flag on the cookie. To me that raises alarm bells. If you can set the HSTS header, why not just set the Secure flag too? I can't think of an answer to this question that would leave me feeling particularly happy.

Answer (score 1):

From a technical perspective, as long as the HSTS lifetime was greater than the maximum cookie lifetime, and the HSTS covered all domains that the cookie would be sent for, then it would protect against the same attack that the `Secure` flag is intended to stop (i.e, stealing the cookie from an unencrypted HTTP connection). This is of course assuming that the browser supports HSTS (which [almost all browsers do](https://caniuse.com/stricttransportsecurity)).

Whether you can convince your QSA that it's an adequate compensating control is a different matter - some QSA are much more flexible than others.